# How can I render 3D graphics which looks like the following image? 3d watercolor rendering

Tags: graphics, 3d

I don't need the dinosaur, just the buildings with details on the buildings, but I would like the 3D graphics to take on this sort of style. Real-time.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part of reproducing this effect in a real-time 3D environment could be handled by the designers, texturing the various meshes in combination with fairly matte shading.

However, there is also a whole field of Computer Graphics research focusing on Non-Photorealistic Rendering (or NPR). There actually have been a lot of published papers on real-time watercolor rendering (to various degrees of success), often using shaders as suggested by xOr.

A good starting point in my opinion would be the work of Adrien Bousseau. An example that comes to mind is his paper "[Interactive watercolor rendering with temporal coherence and abstraction (PDF warning)](http://artis.imag.fr/Publications/2006/BKTS06/watercolor.pdf)". Another one would be "[Watercolor Illustrations from CAD Data (PDF warning)](http://www.cgmi.inf.uni-konstanz.de/publikationen/2008/cadillustrations/Luft%20et%20al.%20--%20Watercolor%20Illustrations%20of%20CAD%20Data.pdf)" by Luft et al.

Now, don't get me wrong, I'm not saying these papers are to be implemented and be done with it. Perhaps they are too science-y for you or simply to complex for whatever system you're trying to create. However, read through them and read through some of the papers they reference to get an idea of the various approaches out there. If nothing else, you will at least have some terms to Google and see if you can find something that suits you.